# exibir posts em múltiplas colunas organizadas por categorias

Tags: php, wordpress

Como tenho um conhecimento limitado de php, gostaria de obter um noção do código necessário para, no wordpress, conseguir o seguinte:

supondo que se tenha x categorias, na página inicial do site deve-se exibir x colunas (uma para categoria), onde em cada coluna devem ser exibidos os n posts mais recentes de cada categoria. nas páginas de cada categoria, deve seguir o mesmo padrão, só que cada coluna será relacionada as sub-categorias da categoria mãe.

alguém poderia me dar algumas dicas de como fazer isso, começando por qual arquivo eu devo alterar para por o código necessário para fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

eu utilizo da seguinte forma:

```
<?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'noticia',
            'posts_per_page' => 3, //Número de posts
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'noticias',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array(
                        'regiao'// Categoria a ser exibida
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
```